# How to sync cassandra and elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Iam looking for a solution that How can i sync cassandra with elastic search i.e. whatever data is written to cassandra ,it should be written to elastic search also

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to develop a capture process that runs on a schedule or in a loop and reads "new" data from Cassandra and sends it to Elasticsearch. The definition of "new" data depends on your Cassandra schema and your applications' insert/update/delete patterns.

Comment: How will know that some data was added or updated in cassandra ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be either done in real time or as the separate batch process .

As and when you get the data to the Cassandra based on the retrieval pattern /query pattern index the data to the Elastic search.

Have the real time processing layer(such as Strom)/Distributed Message broke like Kafka to sync up the data .

Or periodically query the data from Cassandra and ingest to the ES as the separate batch job.